# Dateformat Rails 3.1

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1

I've been banging my head against the table for a while now trying to figure out how to get dates in the format of dd/mm/yyyy to be successfully saved to the database.

I'm using the latest version of Rails (3.1.1) and have added;

```
Time::DATE_FORMATS.merge!(:default => '%d/%m/%Y')
Date::DATE_FORMATS.merge!(:default => '%d/%m/%Y')
```

To my environment.rb file and have also download the en-AU.yml locale file and have set the locale correctly. In my model I have;

```
validates :invoice_date, :presence => true
```

But everytime I submit a form with a date in the format of dd/mm/yyyy (24/11/2011 for example), it always says "Invoice date can't be blank". If I remove that validation rule it saves a null value. What do I have to do to get this work?

Thanks in advance :)

UPDATE:

Form field code is:

```
<input id="invoice_invoice_date" type="text" size="30" name="invoice[invoice_date]">
```

It's really quite strange. It's a nil value if it's out of the range of a mm/dd/yyyy format, however the trace is showing the inputted date... I'm at a loss.

Comment: Can we see the source of your form field?

Comment: I suspect that you are actually passing an empty date for invoice date. Try this, in rails console try to manually create a model with the invoice date set and see if that works. If it does then you may have an issue with your form/controller code. If it does not then I don't know what's happening.

Comment: if I use the date "10/11/2011" it works as it is a valid mm/dd/yyyy date.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest that you use the i18n api: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/i18n.html.  So you can set the default time format for the particular locale in the locale file: example: en.yml.  That might work for you.